# How do I add a new G Suite account to a domain from Google Domains?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-domains

How do I add a G Suite account to a domain purchased from Google Domains?

1. I *just* registered a domain on Google Domains.
2. When I go to the email tab, I see:

   > **Get a custom email address**
   >   Manage G Suite for example.com with the [Admin Console](http://a). [Learn more](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6319254?authuser=1&hl=en)
3. When I tap on Admin Console, it takes me to a log in screen.
4. When I attempt to log in with my @gmail.com account that I used to register the domain, it shows me this error:

   > admin.google.com is for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com. [Learn more](http://www.google.com/support/a/answer/6375836?hl=en)

It seems really odd that I'm stuck in this chicken and egg situation, especially because Google owns both of these products. What's going on? How do I resolve it?

---

**Update:** I tried going to http://gsuite.google.com and creating a new G Suite account there, but after entering my domain name, it showed this error:

> This domain name is already in use. If you own this domain and would like to use G Suite, please follow the steps [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/80610)

This makes me think that because I registered the domain with Google Domains, I must set up G Suite with Google Domains as well. Per the issue above though, I'm stuck in that route too. Any ideas how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should see a button to create the G Suite account when you navigate to Email in Google Domains.

If you *just* registered the domain but see the "Manage G Suite" text, it most likely means someone has created a G Suite account for that domain in the past.

You'll need to delete that old G Suite account associated with that domain before you can create a new one.

I contacted Google Domains support, and they gave me [this link](https://support.google.com/a/contact/recovery_form) to resolve the login issue. One of the items it explicitly calls out is:

> You would like to create a new G Suite account, but are unable to because an account using your domain name already exists.

Submit that [linked form](https://support.google.com/a/contact/recovery_form), and you should be good to go.

If you're having further trouble, they mentioned I should contact G Suite support by going to https://gsuite.google.com, and hitting the Contact Us button.

---

You should receive an email from support asking you to create a CNAME record in Google Domains. This is how you want to do that portion:

1. Google Domains > DNS > Custom resource records
2. These are what you should enter based off of what they mentioned in the email:

   - **Name**: The `Label/Host` they mentioned in the email.
   - **Type**: `CNAME`, as mentioned in the email.
   - **TTL**: The `Time to live` they mentioned in the email (e.g. `1H`).
   - **Data**: The `Destination/Target` they mentioned in the email.